# Execute one update in two distinct conditions PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to perform an update on my table whose version is 3, however I also need to modify the code where the current code is 220.

I need to do this in a single update for performance reasons.

[image]

The current update I'm doing below, is modifying only the version where the code is 220, I also need to change where the version is 3 but without changing the code to 270 where the current code is not 220:

```
UPDATE plan
  SET version = '3', code = 270
  WHERE version LIKE '2'
  AND code = 220;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logic:

```
UPDATE plan
  SET version = '3',
       code = (CASE WHEN code = 220 THEN 270 ELSE code END)
  WHERE version LIKE '2';
```